# Microsoft graph api decrypt change notification (php)

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I have subscribe to msgraph change notification and enabled includeresourcedata.

I’m receiving the data via webhooks. But, i cant decrypt the data.

I have read the document for msgraph but there is nothing for php.

Comment: As mentioned in the document it currently supports the C#, Java and JavaScript:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data#decrypting-resource-data

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the document it currently supports the C#, Java and JavaScript:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data#decrypting-resource-data

If you want it to be available in PHP please raise a feature requesthere: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Hop this helps.